# How to set values of py::dict in C++?

Tags: python, dictionary, pybind11

I want to use a `py::dict` from C++. But `operator[]` does not seem to be defined, and I can't find any information here or in the pybind11 docs of how to add a key/value pair or return a value for a key?

edit: Maybe also important to mention I've got integers as keys.

edit2: Needed to use `py::int_()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see operator[] has two overloads takes either a `py::handle` or `string literal`, so `d["xxx"]` or `d[py::int_{0}]` work but not d[0]  (which would be wrongly resolved as a invalid string literal at compile time,and would cause run-time segment-fault)

```cpp
template <typename Derived>
class object_api : public pyobject_tag {
...
    /** \rst
        Return an internal functor to invoke the object's sequence protocol. Casting
        the returned ``detail::item_accessor`` instance to a `handle` or `object`
        subclass causes a corresponding call to ``__getitem__``. Assigning a `handle`
        or `object` subclass causes a call to ``__setitem__``.
    \endrst */
    item_accessor operator[](handle key) const;
    /// See above (the only difference is that they key is provided as a string literal)
    item_accessor operator[](const char *key) const;
```

also you cannot use std::string as key:

```
std::string key="xxx";
d[key] = 1;  // failed to compile, must change to d[pybind11::str(key)]
```

to make things easier, use pybind11::cast() to explicitly convert any supported  C++ type into corresponding python type, as following:

```
std::string key="xxx";
d[pybind11::cast(1)] = 2
d[pybind11::cast(key)] = 3
```

Answer (score 3):

I see `operator[]` defined for `py::dict`, example:

```cpp
m.def("test", [](){
    py::dict d;
    d[py::int_{0}] = "foo";
    return d;
});
```

```py
>>> example.test()
{10: 'foo'}
```